# Azure SQL Database Corruption - Tables Missing

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We have a windows service that provisions Azure SQL databases for our clients. We are using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Sql API. I have a database named "Green" in a Server located in 'East Asia', Server Version 'v12'. Today we found that my database data are not found. My tables, stored procedures and data are missing.

Comment: Tables usually don't disappear on their own. Have you checked with your entire team to make sure nobody accidentally ran test scripts on the production database? If you truly think there's a database issue (and you're not actively making backups), you'll need to contact support, as there's nothing that could be done to help you here.

Comment: i'm sure about it my team didnot done anything...i have no backup..how to get backup...Its very  essential to have data..

Comment: Azure team  takes backups and you can restore it to any point with in 7 days or more based upon your tier

Comment: Database corruption is a totally different thing than someone / something dropping your tables. You should fix your question.

Comment: how to get backup from azure team.direct me to get backup

Comment: its a miracle data automatically restored without doing anything...Im happy..thank u all

Comment: What actions did you take? Are you sure your data was missing in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

[Restoring deleted Azure SQL Database Using the Azure Portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-restore-deleted-database-portal/)

---

> To restore a database in the Azure Portal do the following:
>
> 1. Open the Azure Portal.
> 2. On the left side of the screen select BROWSE > SQL servers.
> 3. Navigate to the server with the deleted database you want to restore and select the server
> 4. Scroll down to the operations section of your server blade and select Deleted databases: Restore an Azure SQL database
> 5. Select the deleted database you want to restore
> 6. Specify a database name, and click Ok: